# Unable to load js in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

Unable to load js

JSP file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
...
<spring:url value="/resources/home.js" var="homeJS" />
<script src="${homeJS}"></script>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I am getting HTTP Status 404 
The url that it is trying to access is http://localhost:8080/Test/resources/home.js

Comment: try `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

Comment: Tried. Didnt work.

Comment: Try with default servlet `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` All you static resource will be redirect to this servlet and you should see the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was web.xml.
Modified it to :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now working fine